# Automated start of a x-server and own service

Tags: firefox, node.js, ubuntu, x11, init.d

I'm currently developing on a automated info-system which is based on a self-written node-service which is also starting a firefox. This system should run in ubuntu without any controlling of anyone.

My current problems are lying in the autostart of the xServer and our own Service.
I created init.d-scripts which are working and linked in the rc-folders bei rc-update defaults etc.

(Xserver is started by startx in init.d)

The xServer is shutting down when reaching the login-screen of debian (without any gui) and the firefox in our service is reporting that it couldn't reach the display.

Sometines the xServer keeps running but there is no chance reaching it by programs with gui.

Is there a chance to run these setup?

Greetings and a happy new year,

Moritz

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get rid of the X display manager being autostarted, that would be the xdm, gdm, kdm, leightdm, lxdm or something like that.

Then don't forget, that Linux manages its console as VTs (virtual terminals). You can tell the Xserver by the `vt` parameter on the command line, which VT to run on. Note, that the `vt` parameter doesn't has an option dash, e.g.

```
Xorg :100 vt14
```

starts the X server on VT 14. Now it can happen, that some other process switches the VT. So it might make sense to have some watchdog script, that switches back to the choosen VT if on the currently active VT nobody has been logged in (for maintenance for example). To switch a VT use the program `chvt`. And to make sure, that maintenance sessions are not forgotten open you can use some idle-detection program.

Comment: Thank you.
I'll try it the next days and report what happened, hopefully it will do it.

Btw. when should I start the window manager (dwn)?

Comment: @moe: Usually you start the WM as the as the last program of .xinitrc using a exec statement.